# NStimer does not stop on invalidate

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

My timer does not stop even if i am doing "invalidate" and "nil" after reading other links. My code is as below:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *mytimer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; 
            <do some other work>
}

- (void) updateProgressBar :(NSTimer *)timer{
    static int count =0;
    count++;
    NSLog(@"count = %d",count);
    if(count<=10)
    {
        self.DownloadProgressBar.progress= (float)count/10.0f;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"invalidating timer");
        [self.mytimer invalidate];
        self.mytimer = nil;
        return;
    }
    if(count <= 10){
        NSLog(@"count = %d **",count);
        self.mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    }
   }
```

1) The timer goes on infinetly even when invalidating timer else condition is hit after count >10 and count keeps on incrementing.

2) i want to do this on a non-main thread . i want to continue  in viewdidload() after starting the timer.  How to do this ?

I visited other links on SO, all i understood was to call invalidate and nil on timer pointer. I am still facing problems. Could anyone tell me what i am missing here and what i can i do to run the updateProgressBar on background thread and update the progress bar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't need to schedule a timer each time, schedule it once and timer will fire every second for example u can do like below,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimerUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; //to start timer on main thread
 }

//hear schedule the timer 
- (void)startTimerUpdate
 {
    self.mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }

 - (void) updateProgressBar :(NSTimer *)timer{
   static int count =0;
   count++;
   NSLog(@"count = %d",count);
   if(count<=10)
   {
      //self.DownloadProgressBar.progress= (float)count/10.0f;
      NSLog(@"progress:%f",(float)count/10.0f);
   }
   else
   {
      NSLog(@"invalidating timer");
      [self.mytimer invalidate];
      self.mytimer = nil;
      return;
   }
   if(count <= 10){
     NSLog(@"count = %d **",count);
  }
}
```

Comment: oops ! Yes you are absolutely correct . Missed that part .

Comment: Please also suggest how to run the timer on background and update the progress bar ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are scheduling timer multiple time. I think 10 time. just schedule time one time or if require many time then invalidate it that many time as schedule.

Update according to comment : Schedule timer from viewdidload and addobserver means notification on task. when your task will completed invalidate timer. and update your progress in selector method of timer so when you invalidate it it will automatically stop progress bar.

Second thing : you should invalidate timer before moving another viewcontroller also because this objects remains live untill invalidate.

Hope this will hellp :)

Comment: oops !! i am sorry , overlooked that part !!

Comment: Please also give some help to schedule the timer on background thread and continue on viewdidload

Comment: while I am at your answer , just wanted to ask , why does not below work ?[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startTimerupdate) withObject:nil ];    update -   startTimerupdate was called but updateProgressBar was not called meaning timer did not get created ..i guess